# Implementing uneditable line numbers into set of pre tags

Tags: html, contenteditable, pre

I want a group of editable `pre` tags, each one representing a line of text. The line should start off with the line number (uneditable) then be editable after that. If I do `<span contentEditable="false">1 </span><pre contentEditable="true"></pre>` then the `span` is uneditable and the `pre` is editable, but the `pre` is on the next line.

If I change it so the `span` is within the `pre` (`<pre contentEditable="true"><span contentEditable="false">1 </span></pre>`) then the entire thing is editable, and the 1 shows up in the middle of the line with weird tabs indenting it.

How can I get line numbers at the beginning of the `pre` line?

Comment: If you're building a code editor, I would strongly recommend using CodeMirror (http://codemirror.net/) instead, and reading this piece by its author: http://codemirror.net/1/story.html

Answer (score 0):

Simple code editor, without javascript.

http://jsfiddle.net/oswaldoacauan/tpY4Y/

Comment: Enter/Return doesn't make a new line. It extends the current line.

Comment: Not gonna mark it down, but that solution is not great. It may give some ideas to people  but generally the list tag route isn't great unless you want static entry points like a single column spreadsheet.